# MongoDB shell vs. pymongo timeout

Tags: windows, mongodb, timeout, pymongo, firewall

Running windows 10, MongoDB v3.4 and PyMongo 3.5.1, whenever I'm trying to access a MongoDB client that is running on a different machine in my network, I'm getting instant access with the MongoDB shell. However, if I try to connect to the client using PyMongo, it takes exactly 40 sec to perform a database query every single time.
Once I turn off the Windows 10 firewall, then the access is instant with PyMongo. That begs the question, why is PyMongo causing this delay?

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("client_name", 27017,
         serverSelectionTimeoutMS=maxSevSelDelay)
print client.database_names()
```

I tried to set firewall rules that open up the `27017` port for all software and also open up any connection between the 2 machines, to no avail.
I also tried to set the `bind_ip` to `0.0.0.0` as I found explained in other forums in the MongoDB.conf file, which didn't fix my issue either.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Thanks,
Manu